# Reducing size of location cursor on ArcGIS Collector app?

Tags: arcgis-collector

In the Collector app the blue location cursor covers my point features when I get close to one I am navigating to. The point feature then disappears behind the blue dot and I can't tell if I'm centered on the blue dot or near the edge. I need to be precise (w/in 1m), as this location is used for repeat measurements and I would like to avoid installing permanent plot markers if possible.

As a work around I have simply increased the size of my point features to 15pt so they are slightly larger than the blue cursor. This results in a bunch of large dots on the map, which just looks messy.

I would like to reduce the size of the blue location cursor in Collector so I could then make my pnt features small again, thus resulting in a less cluttered map.

Does anyone know if this is possible and if so, how? I have tried a brief internet search but haven't found anything that addresses what I want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently not possible do to in the Collector app. I would recomend posting this under the ArcGIS Ideas page in GeoNet.